# passing data as JSON angularjs to urls in django?

Tags: python, json, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am making an application framework angularjs and django rest.
The list did angularjs through, but the edit what I do with the classic CBV.La question is that I want to pass as a parameter to the url edit the corresponding id value but can not fails the following.

HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Listado de Nucleos{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div ng-controller="comentariosCtrl">
<script>globals = {coresUrl: '{% url "centro" %}'}</script>
<h1>Listado de Nucleos</h1>

<a href="{% url 'core_add'%}" class="btn">Adicionar</a>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Acciones</th>



    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="c in comentarios">
<td>{$c.code$}</td>
<td>{$c.name$}</td>

<td>
    <a href="#" ng-click="removerComentario(c)">remover</a>
    <a href="{% url 'edit' {$c.id$} %}" >editar</a>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Core.js

```
var profileEditApp = angular.module('comentariosApp', ['smart-table']);


profileEditApp.config(['$httpProvider', '$interpolateProvider',
function ($httpProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
    /* for compatibility with django teplate engine */
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
    /* csrf */
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}]);

  profileEditApp.controller('comentariosCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


function getComentarios() {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: globals.coresUrl}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.comentarios = data;
            $scope.lokos= data;

        })
}

getComentarios();
```

views.py

```
class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Core
fields = ['code', 'name']
template_name = 'core_form.html'
success_url = '/structure/core'
```

Error in

```
 <a href="{% url 'edit' {$c.id$} %}" >editar</a>
```

Comment: you can't nest angular expressions. What are your expectations for that `<a>`. Explanation in words would help because syntax looks strange

Comment: <a href="{% url'edit' {$c.id$} %}"> edit </a> when I click on <a> have to go to the edit view with the corresponding id but this is not me let him do

Comment: but what is `url` and string `'edit'` for ? what is expected final result? I think you are confusing server templating with angular templating and would find it a lot easier not using server side templating at all

Comment: My friend, url is used in django, django you know?

Comment: ok...but you have it mixed into an angular expression so is django compiling it or not? My guess is it isn't. What actually gets sent to browser? Just a lot simpler not mixing 2 template systems. All you need from server is a data api

Comment: friend thank you for your comments, we will see that I